# OverridePendingTransition doesn't work if Orientation will change in LandScape programmatically

Tags: java, xamarin, orientation

I am using two activities, in first activity I am using the code below for starting second Activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPerson.class);                      
  startActivity(i);
 overridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_right_in, Resource.Layout.trans_right_out);
 Finish();
```

Then in second activity onCreate Method I am using the code below for changing activity orientation

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(Parameters.Landscape) //Parameters is a static class
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    else
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.filters);
 }
```

The problem is that in that case my animation doesn't work. It works only in PORTRAIT MODE.

Comment: ,You said that you want to change activity orientation LandScape, it only works in portrait mode, before changing, what is the activity orientation?

Comment: Probably unspecified. I don't have set orientation in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I change the orientaion using the following code, and I have no issue.

```
private void Btn2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

    }
```